# What % of users click on Ad position 1 & 2 & 3 in Adword?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search, google-ads, ppc

I want to get the data on what % of users click on all the Ad position in google adwords ?

At least in India it is true that, Most of the Indians compare the price before buying product online. So, in this case, It is very likely that most of them might click at top Ads in Google Adword before reaching a decision on buying.

If most of the users click on 2nd & 3rd position too then I can bid low and save cost in Adwords.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [in depth article](https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/study/2345638/ppc-click-through-rate-by-position-does-rank-matter-data) that answers that question.

[image]
<sub>(source: [searchenginewatch.com](https://searchenginewatch.com/IMG/763/289763/ctr-by-position-chart.png?1434611340))</sub>

```
Avg Pos    CTR
1          12.2%
1.5        4.3%
2          1.5%
2.5        0.5%
3          0.2%
3.5        0.1%
4          0.0%
5          0.0%
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to know how many users clicks on Ad pos 2 or/and 3 as well 1st.

Comment: Didn't it say? Approximately 12 people out of 100 click on 1st position link. 4 people click on second and 1-2 people click on third.